# angular vs vanilla javascript vs jquery, should I use only one of them?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I did all my javascript on front-end in angular. 
My app is not single page application. 
I do not have any routing. I just needed something so my user interaction does not depend on ids or class names of html elements.

With this approach I do not depend on html/css coders. They can do what ever they want without making impact on my javascript logic. But some part  of my project I have to do something like this:

```
var pos = $(".two").find(".active")[0].offsetLeft;
$(".two").scrollLeft(pos - 40);
```

Even that is only two lines of code I am hating that solution because I depend of some elements with class names .two and .active.

**I am not asking how can I do that two lines in agular but wondering if 
there is some framework or javascript lib that can deal with stuff similar to angular**:

1. Directives
2. Services
3. Factories
4. Filters

Most of my, lets say user interaction is done via directives. Most of my logic for example google maps are done via angular directives and angular factories. All of my filters (for example format date is done via angular filters). And at the end all of my ajax calls are done via angular services.

With this approach I have solved major problem and that is code usability (sort of modular approach) then I solved big issue with maintaining code. Anyone can work on this project after me without having to scratch his head for two months in javascript code.

I am having but one issue and that directives are slower then if they are written as pure javascript. When I say slower I mean there is some strange timeout (like 200ms) when html is rendering via directive.

Anyway I would really appreciate some input regarding angular vs plain javascript or jquery, should I mix it or should i do my javascript in angular (or some other framework) only.

Thanks.

Comment: You can do it all in vanilla JS, with that said it helps some projects to have the formality of a framework like AngularJS, some will use an adHoc solution / library like ReactJS or jQuery. I think is has a lot to do with the project and what it requires.

Comment: @JustinHerter  My main concern is/was for code not to be dependable on html, easy to maintain and no code redundancy. As far as I can see only some framework can give me this. Especially part " code not to be dependable on html,"

Comment: If you've got performance problems, I would suggest to address the problem directly. Jumping between frameworks won't help. Performance optimization is advanced topic and usually requires a good knowledge of the framework (this applies to any framework, not just Angular).

Comment: You should give ReactJS a good review if you are looking to use something new, In this case I think plain ole JS should do the trick for performance increases. I have worked extensively with angular and there are great things about it but as with all things some drawbacks as well.

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/comparison.html

Answer (score 0):

I just recommend you try vue.js ,maybe you can check the comparison between react,angular and vue  in https://www.awesomes.cn/vs/10-65-447